# Response byte[] to String[]

Tags: java, android, response, httpresponse

I get a byte[] response from a server with access token information:

```
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
     Log.d("RESPONSE: ", new String(response));           
 }
```

Response is:

```
D/RESPONSE:﹕ {"access_token":"8863e1a8c16e2ce70b4d5a04a209e265bc1efe91","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}
```

How could I parse this response to easily get any object(access_token, expires_in, token_type, scope) of response?

Comment: Looks like JSON data, use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this:

```
 try {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new String(response));
      accessToken = object.getString("access_token");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to convert the response from string to POJO. You can use jackson API to do it. [Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) is an example to do it.

The line responsible for conversion is

```
 mapper.readValue(new File("c://temp/employee.json"), Employee.class);
```